# when is the 'connect' event in nodejs net module emitted?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I have this simple TCP server:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log("New client!");
    });

});

server.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("server running...")
});
```

and then I have another file as **client.js**:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = net.connect({port: 8000},
    function() { 
    console.log('client connected');
});

client.on('error', console.error);
```

I run server in one terminal window and then I run client in other window and expect to see server log "New Client". Although, that doesn't happen. So, when is the 'connect' event exactly emitted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`net.createServer` sets the given function as a listener to the [`connection` event](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connection).

In other words, on the server side, *the socket is already connected when you get the callback*, and the event you're trying to listen to isn't emitted on an already connected socket.

Comment: So, does that mean the callback I supply to `net.createServer` is essentially what gets executed on `connect` event?
Also, how can I explicitly emit connect event then since it can't be emitted on already connected socket?

Comment: @Jatin Yes, the callback is automatically registered on the `connected` event. To manually emit a `connect` event, you can use [emitter.emit()](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2).

Answer (score 0):

I made a different test. The server object has "timeout" property. When you call the follow code:

`server.setTimeout(500);` //Now after 0,5 second you can call "connection" event.
The default value is 120000.

But, I still have no idea what this change will cause.